# Wordpress pretty permalinks /w Pretty query parameters (For sort) via ModRewrite

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I currently have wordpress pages that that can be viewed via both the index page (all the posts) and also the category pages.

My current permalink structure is 'http://www.mysite.com/%postname%/' which is neat and i would like to keep.

Current examples..

Home page (post list)
   http://www.mysite.com/

Category page (filtered post list - filter on category)
   http://www.mysite.com/categoryname/

Any post list needs to be order (by choice of the user) by any of the following parameters...

Oldest->Newest    ,   Newest->Oldest   ,  Expensive->Cheapest   ,  Cheapest->Expensive   ,  HighestRated->LowestRated   ,   LowestRated->HighestRated

I have handled all the sorting correctly in the functions.php and it retrieves from from GET parameter set. (the last 4 are custom meta attributes which I have sorted/handled correctly)

Examples are...
http://www.mysite.com?SortBy=Newest

http://www.mysite.com/categoryname?SortBy=HighestRated

I can't get a correct functioning .htaccess file with ModRewrite that achieves this....

I would like them to look like these (for the 2 examples above)

http://www.mysite.com/SortBy/Newest/

http://www.mysite.com/categoryname/SortBy/HighestRated

My webserver is running Apache on Linux server.

My current .htaccess file looks like this...

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

It doesn't seem to be doing my current re-write actions but I presume these are handled by Wordpress elsewhere??

Comment: You need [WP Rewrite API](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Rewrite). Wordpress handles all rewrite rules with its api.

Comment: So I have to write a function to do it?

Comment: Ofcourse yes! you should look at [add_rewrite_ruke](http://codex.wordpress.org/Rewrite_API/add_rewrite_rule) function.

Comment: Sure - I'm looking any pointers!?!! It doesn't make sense to me lll

Comment: @MattTheNinja Did you achieve this  ?

Comment: @YoYo no idea mate, that was 5 years ago! I can't remember what I had for breakfast this morning. I also use nginx howadays, far easier to write such things.

Answer (score 0):

Use the add_query_arg WordPress function. WordPress is designed to reject any URL query parameters that it doesn’t recognize. You will need to tell WordPress about the new parameter(s) you will be sending via a URL.

Reference:
http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_query_arg

"Retrieve a modified URL (with) query string.

You can rebuild the URL and append a new query variable to the URL query by using this function. You can also retrieve the full URL with query data."

Comment: Thanks, I still understand how this answers my question. This seems to be relating to creating Links with arguments added.

I want to change a query parameter into a pretty URL. If this does do this could you provide an example like my question suggest I just can't get my head around it based on the example WP have given in that article(if it's correct)